# Echo to a different server using python

Tags: python, shell, echo

The following echo command works properly while running it manually, i.e it reaches to the mentioned server.

```
echo "{\"status\": \"DOWN\", \"macaddr\": \"xyz-123p\", \"topic\": \"switches\"}" | nc rms-kus-e003.corp.port.net 11
```

I tried to automate it using the following method. The echo is displaying on the sending server but not reaching to the destination server.

```
import os
import subprocess
e = 'echo echo \\"{\\\\\\"status\\\\\\": \\\\\\"DOWN\\\\\\",  \\\\\\"macaddr\\\\\\": \\\\\\"xyz\-123p\\\\\\", \\\\\\"topic\\\\\\": \\\\\\"switches\\\\\\"}\\" \| nc rms\-aus\-e003\.corp\.port\.net 11'
subprocess.call(e, shell=True)
#for i in range (0,10):
#   os.system('echo echo \\"{\\\\\\"status\\\\\\": \\\\\\"DOWN\\\\\\",  \\\\\\"macaddr\\\\\\": \\\\\\"xyz\-123p\\\\\\", \\\\\\"topic\\\\\\": \\\\\\"switches\\\\\\"}\\" \| nc rms\-aus\-e003\.corp\.port\.net 11 ')
```

Please suggest some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your crazy quoting is what's breaking it.  A minimal fix would be

```
#import os  # not needed
import subprocess
e = r'''echo 'echo "{\"status\": \"DOWN\", \"macaddr\": \"xyz-123p\", \"topic\": \"switches\"}"' | nc rms-aus-e003.corp.port.net 11'''
subprocess.call(e, shell=True)
```

Notice how the pipe character in particular isn't backslashed.  There is no reason to backslash dashes or dots either, as they aren't shell metacharacters. (You need to backslash dots in a regular expression to make them *match* a literal dot, but this isn't a regex at all. I don't think there is a common situation where backslash-escaping a dash is necessary or correct<sup>1</sup>.)

Your repeated `echo` somehow suggests that you are trying to send this as a command to `nc` for the remote server to execute, but that's not what your shell command does; it just prints the JSON string to the socket.

Either way, just connecting to `nc` from Python would be smoother, and avoids the fugly `shell=True`:

```
s = subprocess.Popen(['nc', 'rms-aus-e003.corp.port.net', '11'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
s.communicate('{"status": "DOWN", "macaddr": "xyz-123p", "topic": "switches"}')
s.close()
```

If you have Python 3.5+ you can further simplify to

```
subprocess.run(['nc', 'rms-aus-e003.corp.port.net', '11'],
    input='{"status": "DOWN", "macaddr": "xyz-123p", "topic": "switches"}')
```

But then of course, `nc` in this simple case doesn't do anything Python can't do, so the simplest possible solution is probably

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('rms-aus-e003.corp.port.net', '11'))
s.sendall(b'{"status": "DOWN", "macaddr": "xyz-123p", "topic": "switches"}\r\n')
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

(This is slightly speculative about the values the receiving socket will accept. CRLF line termination is common in network protocols, though I suppose if the recipient is U*x it will be perfectly happy without the `\r` and possibly not particularly like for it to be there.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Some regex dialects allow a backslashed dash inside a character class to put a literal dash instead of a range. So `re.search(r'[:\-;]') is a cumbersome way to match a colon, a dash, or a semicolon. The less obfuscated syntax would be`re.search('[-:;]')` which is properly unambiguous.